# Lack of practical insights into using Play+Scala vs. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, scala

We (my team) is starting on a cloud-hosted web based application. We embarked upon Scala+Play as the server side web application. Since no one knew Scala in my team (previous experience in Java/Java Script/Python/C++) all of us are experiencing a steep learning curve. After spending a few weeks on learning basics of Scala, we started with play-scala-starter example as a basis. It took a few days of time for a team member to create a prototype GET+POST API handler accessing mysql DB.
Given significant efforts and the time spent on Scala, a team member for the sake of comparison built the same prototype functionality using node.js in just half-a-day (4-5 hours). That was a revelation for all of us. To add to that the Internet is replete with node.js success stories used in enterprise grade applications (note that for front-end anyway we are going to use JS based framework e.g. Angular, React, etc.).
Now as a team we are debating on next approach - play+scala or node.js. We don't want to take a decision based on short-term gains or to avoid initial struggle in ramping-up. That's why posting this question here to get real-world insights. If this is a wrong-place to ask such questions then please suggest appropriate one. Most likely this question will be closed as it is of 'discussion' type.
NOTE: This post is not to criticize any of the approaches. So apologies in advance.

Comment: I think a more important metric than prototyping speed, is refactoring-large-codebase speed, which a good typesystem is crucial for

Comment: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2015/04/22/scala-vs-node-js-as-a-restful-backend-server/

Answer (score 2):

This is what you should expect when you "take a quick look into Scala and build a prototype". Scala is a long-term investment. If you want to get all the benefits of its type system, expressiveness and functional programming concepts, it will take much more that a few weeks (I've been doing it for almost three years now and am still learning all the time).

I work at a successful startup which started out with its backend being written in NodeJS because of the same reasoning as you described, but now they are doing all their new stuff in Scala (not Play, but a more FP-oriented framework [Finch](https://finagle.github.io/finch/); however I've been working with Play at my previous two jobs and it's definitely if not the most widespread Scala web framework, then definitely out there near the top). So don't worry, it's really heavily used in production. For example, my [favourite chess portal](https://lichess.org/) is fully done in Play stack. There were many others [three years ago](https://www.quora.com/What-startups-or-tech-companies-are-using-Play-Framework) and the list is surely much bigger by now (and of course, these are just the most popular ones; also note that this is the list for those who have specifically declared to be using Play framework, because list for Scala in general would include many other giants, such as Twitter, Coursera, Soundcloud, Spotify, Foursquare, Netflix, AirBnB, Quora, Tumblr, eBay etc.).

When done right, functional programming (oh yes btw, I'm not even considering OOP-style Scala) gives you a lot of safety and security. You know that old saying - "I used to feel like an expert in JS and nothing worked. Now I feel like an amateur in Haskell, but everything works". But compared to Haskell, I feel that Scala has a lot more traction. I understand your worries when you google something related to NodeJS and then the same for Scala, but trust me, once you get going you will realize that Scala has a big community, a lot of material on various blogs/forums/stackoverflow and a [huge ecosystem](https://github.com/lauris/awesome-scala).

As far as NodeJS itself is concerned, you will notice a lot of similarities with Play, both being asynchronous event-driven frameworks. But talking about JS as a language, if you invest time into Scala to become proficient enough with it, you will be asking yourself how could you ever have lived without certain aspects of it, most notably its type system (TypeScript sucks btw).

I'm aware that I'm being subjective, but it's an opinion-based question. It should (and probably will) be marked as too broad / non-constructive / off-topic / unclear, but instead of just flagging it, I decided to try to encourage you guys into making a good long-term decision. Find some extra time, go through a [good introductory book](https://booksites.artima.com/programming_in_scala_3ed), enroll into the [Coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1) (started yesterday) and this time next month you will be feeling much more confident with it. Of course, one month is a long time if you need a prototype tomorrow, but if timing is really that critical, then I would always advise to go with the technology you're most comfortable with and leave experimenting for a more relaxed project. Otherwise you will not only be frustrated, but deliver a poor product.

Comment: slouc: you addressed my main questions spot-on. I agree that Scala is not something to consider for a short-term prototyping. Yes, as always there is a pressure to deliver as of today. Yet, we as a team decided to go with Scala as it offers long-term benefits vs. Node. Java we avoided deliberately because of too much boiler-plate code and scalability limitations (Java8 might solve some of these concerns). Mainly two things slowed us down:
1. Vastness of scala language itself
2. Most of the times google does not return the suggestions as is the case with Node or Java.
Thanks for details.

Comment: @NKM Scala is indeed a pretty vast language. Resources that I listed (book and coursera course) are made by the creator of Scala himself and they take you through the path that makes the most sense, making the learning curve as pleasant as possible. If you devote the following six weeks to learning Scala via these resources, you will be over the hump. And once you're done with that, you will be completely competent to write quality web services in Play. You will be finding more and more advanced concepts as you go, but just take them one-at-a-time and it will be a fun and rewarding process.

Comment: Apart form this stack overflow forum, gitter chat room and scala users forum (scala-lang) is there any other community forum which I am not aware of ?

Comment: There's also a Slack channel (actually many of them) and r/scala on Reddit. Twitter has a strong community too, but it's more for "what's new" than asking help (for news there are also others such as Scala Times or CakeSolution's ThisWeekInScala). There are also people on IRC but I'm not using that. I'm sure there aree other groups too which I don't know of or can't remember right now. Add dozens of cool conferences and hundreds of local meetup groups all over the world (sometimes it's just a handful of enthusiasts meeting for a beer, but e.g. here in Berlin we're ~1200).

Comment: I am taking the Scala course on Coursera. I posted a question into the forum:
https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun1/discussions/weeks/2/threads/jWta4Fi0EeeHCRK3oa8qzA
Basically the question is about how 'Set' is defined and used.
So far no response to my question. Can you help here ?

Comment: I can't open that link.

Comment: Oops...didn't see your comment. I am pasting the question here:
The assignment defines:
    `type Set = Int => Boolean
    //(Int => Boolean) is an anonymous function
    //Then I use this as:
    > val a = Set(3)
    > contains(a, 4) //returns false
    > contains(a, 3) //returns true
    > a(3) // returns true
    > a(2) // returns false`
Question: since the anonymous function is not yet defined in terms of how it operates on the parameter Int, how do above operations work ? In other words I am not able to understand how does type Set know that a number is its element ?

Comment: somehow the code formatting is not happening correctly when I posted the comment above.

Comment: There is some code that you're using but didn't paste, such as `contains`. Furthermore, the `Set` you're creating is most likely the one from scala predef; the type you defined is something else. I'm willing to help you, but comments section of an unrelated SO question is definitely not the right place for that :) besides, I can only help you with general advice regarding your Coursera course. For specific questions use the Coursera discussion board. If you need some advice, feel free to drop me a [private message on twitter](https://twitter.com/sinisalouc) )

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you're new to a language : EXpect time. So I'm not surprised that doing the prototype in Node.js is way faster.

My advice : Stick to Java in this case. It's easier if you're coming from C++ / Java / JS.

I won't recommend nodejs from a technical point of view : It has scalability issues, and Play is build on Akka, so you get all the Akka goodies for free. Getting that right in another language is hard. As in : Really hard.

In short : Start with Play Java, and do the move to Scala later on.

Comment: We would have stuck to Java except for the reasons as mentioned above in my comment.